# [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I get the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSA
```

Here is my code:

```
static NSArray * clone(NSArray * a, NSUInteger b)
{
    // return a.slice(b);
    return [a subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(b, a.count - b)];
}
// swap: function(a, b) {
static NSArray * swap(NSArray *a, NSUInteger b)
{
    NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:a];

// var t1, t2;
id t1, t2;

// t1 = a[0];
t1 = array.firstObject;

// t2 = a[b % a.length];
t2 = array[b % a.count];

// a[0] = t2;
array[1] = t2;

// a[b] = t1;
array[b] = t1;

// return a;
return array.copy;
}
```

I'm confused on why it is giving me the error. This is just a snippet of the code, This comes from a modified version of HCYoutubeParser.

Comment: Read the error. The array is empty. You can't access elements of an empty array. Point out the exact line causing the error. Use the debugger to step through the code and determine why the array is empty.

Comment: it throws here: t2 = array[b % a.count]; It returns with 0 objects, so it throws. How do i make it skip over certain parts of code if it has 0 objects

Comment: That means that `array` is empty which means that the `a` array is empty. Find where you call `swap` and see why you pass in an empty array. Better yet, fix your `swap` function so it handles arrays with any number of elements.

Comment: im using this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samnung/YPlayer/6c4a0573b9739522d56f9d34195f64685fbcdda7/3rdParty/HCYoutubeParser.m

Comment: How do I change the swap function for this? kinda a noobs sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Because simply if you debug your application, you'll find that in this line

```
array[1] = t2;
```

The variable array doesn't have 2 items to access the item #1, it contains either 0 or 1 item, you should do a check like this

```
if (array.count >= 2) {
    array[1] = t2;
}
```

Comment: So it brings back a error that there are 0 objects, and it crashes. heres the link to the code im using: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samnung/YPlayer/6c4a0573b9739522d56f9d34195f64685fbcdda7/3rdParty/HCYoutubeParser.m

Comment: Actually I guess the code is good because I can't see any access to the second item of the array, array[1] go and search for it

Comment: search for an array? I don't know what to do:( It throws because there is 0 objects, could i make it go to another file if there are 0 objects?

Comment: Simply make the check, if (array.count > 0) {

Comment: But how do i link it to go to another file?

Comment: This wasn't your question in the first place, so help me to understand what files you are talking about

Comment: So I want to create a new file, without the deciphering in the code. So if (array.count > 0) it goes to the new file

Comment: @RobertMyers, its not possible and not disturb the existing code.  If you make a new function, you'll need to change every _call_ to that function.  Better to just fix it in place.  But its troubling to begin with that the original author didn't see this case.  Also, your code is already changed, look at the line "array[1] = t2;", the original has it correctly as "array[0] = t2;"

Comment: I changed it and it still crashes. What it does is it deciphers vevo music videos, but it only can decipher vevo videos, if it doesn't have a cipher, then it throws an error and says their is 0 objects. How do I make it to where it can still load the video even if it doesn't have a cipher.