# Xcode 8.1 & 8.2.1 crashes on startup

Tags: xcode, xcode8

This just started happening while I writing some (iOS) code in XCode.  Looks to be part of the IDE. crash log says the IDE had a NSRangeException.  Any ideas how to find the problem or reset so I go back?

I've cleared the derived data for this project and launched Xcode again.  It shows for a second and then crashes.  When I go look at the derived data folder it looks like Xcode started to create the /index/debug/iphonesimulator10.1-x86_64/.xcindex/db.xcindexdb... files and then crashed during that process.  So might have something to do with the simulator which I did have running at the time of first crash, but I was not using it.

I tried rolling back to a previous version of project.pbxproj and still having the same crash issue.  And Xcode only crashes on this project.  I can open others fine.

UPDATE:  I upgraded to Xcode 8.2.1 and still having the same issue.  I am used Pods and so that means I'm using a workspace.  Not sure if this is causing any problems.

Here's the lovely crash report.

```
Process:               Xcode [835]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               8.1 (11544)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-11544000000000000~4
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [835]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-01-24 21:22:55.528 -0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.1 (16B2555)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        xxx


Time Awake Since Boot: 610 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 8B62
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSRangeException): *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: Creation Backtrace for Notification Token:

  0   -[_DVTNotificationReceiver initWithBlock:queue:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1   -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) dvt_addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
  2   -[_IDENavigatorOutlineViewDataSource setRootItems:] (in IDEKit)
  3   -[IDENavigatorOutlineView _updateRootItems:sortDescriptors:] (in IDEKit)
  4   -[IDENavigatorOutlineView setRootItems:] (in IDEKit)
  5   -[IDENavigatorOutlineView _updateBoundContentArrayOrSet] (in IDEKit)
  6   -[IDENavigatorOutlineView updateBoundContentArray] (in IDEKit)
  7   -[NSObject(DVTBindingUtilities) updateBoundValueForBinding:] (in DVTKit)
  8   -[DVTBindingHelper observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (in DVTKit)
  9   NSKeyValueNotifyObserver (in Foundation)
 10   NSKeyValueDidChange (in Foundation)
 11   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
 12   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
 13   _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify (in Foundation)
 14   -[IDEBatchFindNavigator updateScopeItems:] (in IDEKit)
 15   __44-[IDEBatchFindNavigator setupLocationPicker]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEKit)
 16   -[NSObject(DVTObservingConvenience) _dvt_newObserverForKeyPath:options:owner:creationBacktrace:withHandlerBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 17   -[NSObject(DVTObservingConvenience) dvt_newObserverForKeyPath:options:withHandlerBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 18   -[IDEBatchFindNavigator setupLocationPicker] (in IDEKit)
 19   -[IDEBatchFindNavigator viewDidInstall] (in IDEKit)
 20   -[DVTViewController _viewDidInstall] (in DVTKit)
 21   -[_DVTViewController_ViewLifecycleInterpositions viewDidMoveToWindow] (in DVTKit)
 22   -[NSView _setWindow:] (in AppKit)
 23   -[NSView addSubview:] (in AppKit)
 24   __42-[DVTReplacementView _setupViewController]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
 25   DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 26   -[DVTReplacementView _setupViewController] (in DVTKit)
 27   -[DVTReplacementView installedViewController] (in DVTKit)
 28   -[DVTReplacementView layoutTopDown] (in DVTKit)
 29   -[DVTLayoutView_ML _reallyLayoutIfNeededTopDown] (in DVTKit)
 30   +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 31   +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 32   +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 33   +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 34   +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 35   +[DVTLayoutView_ML _doRecursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:completionCallBackHandlers:currentLayoutPass:needsSecondPass:] (in DVTKit)
 36   +[DVTLayoutView_ML _recursivelyLayoutSubviewsOfView:populatingSetWithLaidOutViews:] (in DVTKit)
 37   -[DVTLayoutView_ML viewWillDraw] (in DVTKit)
 38   -[NSView(NSInternal) _sendViewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 39   -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 40   -[NSView(NSInternal) _sendViewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 41   -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 42   -[NSView(NSInternal) _sendViewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 43   -[NSView viewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 44   -[NSView(NSInternal) _sendViewWillDraw] (in AppKit)
 45   -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:] (in AppKit)
 46   -[NSView displayIfNeeded] (in AppKit)
 47   -[NSWindow displayIfNeeded] (in AppKit)
 48   ___NSWindowGetDisplayCycleObserver_block_invoke.6219 (in AppKit)
 49   __37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 50   CA::Transaction::run_commit_handlers(CATransactionPhase) (in QuartzCore)
 51   CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) (in QuartzCore)
 52   CA::Transaction::commit() (in QuartzCore)
 53   __37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke.31 (in AppKit)
 54   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 55   __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation)
 56   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 57   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 58   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 59   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 60   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 61   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 62   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 63   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 64   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 65   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 66   start (in libdyld.dylib)

Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3   -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4   -[_IDENavigatorOutlineViewDataSource outlineView:child:ofItem:] (in IDEKit)
  5   refreshRowEntryItemAndLevelInfo (in AppKit)
  6   -[NSOutlineView reloadItem:reloadChildren:] (in AppKit)
  7   -[IDENavigatorOutlineView reloadItem:reloadChildren:] (in IDEKit)
  8   __83-[_IDENavigatorOutlineViewDataSource _processNavigableItemGraphChangeNotification:]_block_invoke.735 (in IDEKit)
  9   +[NSAnimationContext(DVTNSAnimationContextAdditions) dvt_nonAnimatedBlock:] (in DVTKit)
 10   -[IDENavigatorOutlineView suspendEditingWhilePerformingBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 11   -[_IDENavigatorOutlineViewDataSource _processNavigableItemGraphChangeNotification:] (in IDEKit)
 12   DVTInvokeWithLazyFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 13   __48-[_DVTNotificationReceiver receiveNotification:]_block_invoke.42 (in DVTFoundation)
 14   -[_DVTNotificationReceiver receiveNotification:] (in DVTFoundation)
 15   __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ (in CoreFoundation)
 16   _CFXRegistrationPost (in CoreFoundation)
 17   ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
 18   -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] (in CoreFoundation)
 19   _CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)
 20   -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)
 21   -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in DVTFoundation)
 22   -[IDENavigableItemCoordinator _postNotificationNamed:forChangedItems:] (in IDEKit)
 23   -[IDENavigableItemCoordinator _delayedPostGraphAndPropertyChangeNotifications] (in IDEKit)
 24   __48-[DVTDelayedInvocation initWithTarget:selector:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 25   -[DVTDelayedInvocation runBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 26   __NSFirePerformWithOrder (in Foundation)
 27   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 28   __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation)
 29   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 30   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 31   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 32   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 33   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 34   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 35   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 36   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 37   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 38   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 39   start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563918/nsarraym-objectatindex-index-2-beyond-bounds-for-empty-array

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks. but this is Xcode crashing because of apple's code, not mine.  This stack trace belongs to Xcode.

Comment: How about the others project? Crash only when open a specified project?

Comment: then enable the zombies and check once

Comment: Does Xcode crash when **not** opening a project? Simply launching Xcode directly?

Comment: @raidfive.  no.  I can open Xcode by itself and it does not crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I delete the "build" folder in my Xcode project folder then start Xcode it works! (rather then derived data folder in the Xcode user library folder.)

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on the file .xcworkspace > Show Package Contents
- Delete the xcuserdata folder

Ref:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/271128/230590

Answer (score -1):

May be you could update your Xcode to the latest version ie: 8.2.1 . :)

Comment: I updated to 8.2.1 (Current Latest) and still having issues.   It's interesting that I wasn't already running the latest.  AppStore never showed me there were updates for Xcode... anyways still no love...